# How do I set this default time to a.ast which is in the ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="a in alphabet">
          <input type="time" ng-model="a.bst">
          <input type="time" ng-model="a.ast">
      </div>
      <input type="time" ng-model="b.bst" >
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.a={};
       $scope.b={};
       $scope.a.ast = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '09:30');
       $scope.a.bst = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '08:30');
       $scope.b.bst = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '07:30');
    });
    </script>

    <p>how do i set this default time to a.ast which is in the ng-repeat?</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

How do I set this default time to `a.ast` which is in the ng-repeat?.......................................

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG36GH125538

Comment: what you exactly want? which default time you want to assign in a.ast? and what is data in alphabet?

Comment: $scope.a.ast = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '09:30');

Comment: i have changed the code, now its clear...  i just want set default time 09:30 to a.ast same as b.bst, but i'm not able to set it because "a"  is in ng-repeat.

Comment: could it be because the name 'a' collides with another 'a' defined on the scope? what if you use another name, like z in alphabet (and change the contents of ng-repeat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.alphabet=[{bst:'',ast:''}];
   $scope.b={};
   $scope.ast = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '09:30');
   $scope.bst = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '08:30');
   $scope.b.bst = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '07:30');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="a in alphabet">
      <input type="time" ng-model="a.bst"  ng-init="a.bst = bst">
      <input type="time" ng-model="a.ast"  ng-init="a.ast = ast"><br/>
  </div>
  <input type="time" ng-model="b.bst" >
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry jenny, i have changed the code can you see it again, now it's simple just wants to set the time to a.ast element

Comment: @RaaZuSaH which timing you want to set? what do you mean by this default time?

Comment: Happy to help you. @RaaZuSaH